# What can I do about posters that derail the question with a discussion about best practices?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027202/how-to-query-the-database-table-with-no-primary-key?noredirect=1) question, and one thing I noticed was that, even though I pretty clearly stated that I understand the importance of primary keys in databases (but that it's avoidable in my particular situation), I still got responses about how important primary keys are in databases.

Of course, in this situation, I didn't receive too much backlash, but I've certainly seen other questions where the answer never surfaces because of all the answers (or comments) discussing the merits of doing it however the poster believes to be the *right* way.

In short: if an OP is trying to avoid letting a detail unrelated to a question from derailing the conversation, what can they do if/when it starts to happen? (Keep in mind that this is, of course, assuming that the details *are indeed unrelated*!)

Edit: it seems as though I've received a downvote for this question; could whoever did that please explain what they dislike about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, make sure you have really adequately explained your special situation, and the comment really does not raise any point you should clarify / address some more.
In nearly every case, you can stop reading right here.

There's a simple reason we expect the asker to explain why he does something inefficient, too complicated, error-prone or even downright dangerous.
For the same reason, it can be reasonable to presume the asker does not understand anyway:

In many cases, **even if the he stated that he is aware of the fact**, he might not appreciate all the down-sides, or the reason he gave is *not sufficient* to accept them (common sense should apply here).

The situation is actually so bad that answerers will often comment or even answer after **quick-scanning and recognizing one of the dozen common mistakes** in the field, in the reasonable assumption that they have already identified the actual problem (I specifically do not exonerate myself here).

Referring to ["but I'm a special snowflake" (no you are not <sub>(99.99% certainty)</sub>!!)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267157), this **even applies to theoretical questions** where OP states they want to understand what something does *even though they would never use it, because it it a) and b) and certainly c) as well*, because many answerers are de-sensitized.

Last but not least, if you insist on proposing / doing something an unorthodox way, you are quite likely to receive exhortations to follow the one true way.
Indicating that other way as well might get you off without downvotes, but will not redeem you in the eyes of the true acolytes.

Accept that *this is the internet*, and a certain amount of dross will always be with us; a thick skin is a valuable and neccessary asset, but **don't forego reading and understanding**, or you become part of the problem.

Comment: Someone on the internet is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest either listening to them or explaining why this is a special exception.  Because when someone claims "but I'm a special snowflake" they're almost always wrong.

Comment: I feel like it's a little silly to expect every user to explain why they're doing something that they've clearly considered, but I guess that's just the nature of the beast.

Comment: I feel its more than a little arrogant to come somewhere because you need help and not listen to the advice given because it isn't the advice you want.

Comment: @Dan: The problem is too many askers **don't** know. The oher one is speed-reading and pattern-recognition: After the 234th time you see OP doing the same bad thing in (insert tag here), you expect it, and automatically fire off the coment without making double-sure it's appropriate.

Comment: @Gabe: He said he explicitly mentioned in the question that **yes, he knows, but for some reason wants do do it that way anyway**. So, the *advice* is simply inappropriate.

Comment: @Deduplicator I like how you're defending both sides of this conversation, haha. Anyways, that's a fair point. On truly unrelated questions (see EJP's comment on the my question above), should I just flag them? I'm assuming that's the proper recourse here.

Comment: Why do you think the comment needs to be flagged, @Dan?

Comment: I've flagged it, but I mentioned which was bothering me in my comment.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm actually totally fine with your comment that starts "The problem is that too many askers **don't** know" - make it a response and I'll mark it as the answer