# This answer shouldn't have been deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I posted

> "Agile2D is very old, I'm almost sure it isn't maintained anymore, you should switch to GLG2D"

as an answer to this question:  [Java3D classes not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365593/java3d-classes-not-found)

Actually, the person who posted this question uses a mix of Java 3D with Agile2D according to his stacktrace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/media/opengl/GLCapabilitiesChooser at
>   jpl.mipl.jade.jadis.agile2d.swing.JOGLPluggableRenderer.notifyBeforeSetRootPane(JOGLPluggableRenderer.java:105)

Therefore, my answer is neither inherently wrong nor off topic. Please undelete my answer.

Edit.: The downvote isn't fair because one of the moderator who deleted my answer advises SO users to use Meta in case of disagreement, which is what I am doing.

Comment: "The downvote isn't fair..." The downvotes on Meta? As the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) mentions, votes on Meta often express agreement or disagreement. Folks have most likely been disagreeing with your contention that your answer should not have been deleted. If you wanted to dispute the deletion, bringing it up on Meta was indeed the correct option. That you got downvotes has no bearing on it.

Comment: Ok but I still think that downvoting without making any comment isn't very helpful because it doesn't tell me why they disagree. Moreover, I challenge them to make Agile2D and Java 3D 1.5 work together with JOGL on a very recent Mac OS X without using the deprecated Java for OS X provided by Apple as they need a version of JOGL (1.1.1?) which doesn't support recent Macs (fixed in JOGL 2, which is incompatible with Agile2D and Java 3D 1.5 but compatible with GLG2D and Java 3D 1.6.0).

Answer (score 21):

> Therefore, my answer isn't inherently wrong or off topic.

It isn't an answer either. Post it as a comment.

Comment: Which was why it was flagged as NAA and deleted.

Comment: @bluefeet I don't think so as using GLG2D with Java 3D 1.6.0 and JOGL 2 would solve his problem and I already advised him to use Java 3D 1.6.0 and JOGL 2 (then I shouldn't repeat myself in an answer).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268228/839601

Comment: @gnat GLG2D is "another technology" but it is like a sequel of Agile2D, it can be used for similar purposes and Agile2D isn't maintained for about ten years. How could I have advised something viable based on it then? "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" then I think that my answer was helpful. Agile2D and Java 3D 1.5 don't rely on the same version of JOGL than Java 3D 1.6.0.

Comment: @gouessej yeah I think formal quality standards in theory can be stretched to consider your answer legitimate. It seems to be somewhat in the gray area, because [without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269310/839601 "related meta discussion"): _"Though Agile2D is very old, I'm almost sure it is still maintained, you should avoid switching to GLG2D"_