# What to do with answer that is up for review because it uses a different technology

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, specific-answer

I have a review task for Answer up for review because it uses a different technology. OP was looking for JS and this is a CSS solution. The answer is viable and highly scored, but there are others upset.

Question:[How to capitalize first letter of each word, like a 2-word city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/javascript-how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city)

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878797

I found [Answers that use a different technology than what is asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268190/answers-that-use-a-different-technology-than-what-is-asked) but that doesn't address my issue? Should I recommend deletion or call it a useful answer?

Comment: All of that kerfuffle over a 6 year old answer...

Comment: Hopefully the principles detailed pertain to situations more current :)

Comment: Personally have seen lots of css solutions that were perfectly valid for javascript questions (as in your example).....when OP didn't realize that css could be even used to solve problem. Sometimes need to maintain an open mind

Comment: The answer was useful for over 100 people, while it made around 20 upset. It's not accepted, it's just another answer what add something useful. Why the whole story if there is none? Simply downvote if you don't like the answer of find it inapropriate and move on.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you feel that the answer fails to properly answer the question due to not meeting constraints of the question, you're more than welcome to downvote that answer.

It in no way qualifies the answer for deletion; voting to delete an answer just because you don't think it's a good answer to the question is highly inappropriate.

Comment: Thx. I'm not looking to down vote the answer. The reasons that others have flagged the question is because it offers a solution in a different technology than what the OP asked for. Solutions are viable in the OP technology. The answerer has posted an alternative in a completely different technology. It is highly upvoted but it is now in review. So, my question is not whether I think its a good answer, but rather is it appropriate to recommend deletion for an answer that intentionally utilized a different technology when there are viable solutions in the OP technology?

Comment: @ShawnMehan I'm aware that that's the question that you're asking, and I've given my answer to it.  If you feel that the answer fails to properly answer the question that is a perfectly fine reason to downvote, it's an entirely inappropriate reason to vote to delete something.

Comment: I agree. Even if answers don't use the technology requested or meet all the constraints supplied, they can still be useful to gain another perspective of the problem and how to solve it. If you feel an answer is irrelevant and adds nothing, then downvoting is the way to go

Comment: @Servy, I see. The *you* in your answer was not specifically *me* in this case but rather *anyone* reading the answer. So, users can down vote but the flag to delete should be declined. ty

Comment: Quite regularly the best answer is the one that points out there's a completely different way to do what you're flaying about with. Deleting that for purist reasons is not serving the users.

Comment: @GeorgeM You can ask the correct question instead, you know?

Comment: @Braiam yes rephrasing the question could be a good way to go about it.  But I don't see much difference with someone telling me 'it's much easier to do get there this other way'.  The literal answer isn't useless by any means, but it can usually be found in the docs.  The larger answer of what method is best is one of the main reasons to be here. imho.

Comment: @GeorgeM the thing is that those that look for the question that that answer answers (try saying that fast three times) will not find the answer, unless they try to do it wrong... basically, we act like the tools clerk that waits for people to shoot themself in the foot to get a nail in the wall instead of offering a hammer from the get go when they come around.

Comment: @Braiam if you put it that way, fixing the answer method is totally reasonable, and the right thing to do.  Even if you just made me snort coffee up my nose..