# Answers for different technology intentionally posted on popular question

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

I am looking for an answer to the following scenario:

Somebody is searching the correct syntax to combine `INSERT INTO` and a CTE in [bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigquery). However, search engines only yield some popular Stack Overflow questions in other comparable, but ultimately incompatible technologies. After figuring out the right syntax the user posts [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470439/8291949) on a popular question tagged [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) "**for discoverability reasons**". Is this [fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268228/8291949) - in general or for discoverability's sake? Liable [to downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349114/8291949)? Or actually not-an-answer?

The linked answers address a slightly different scenario, i.e. interchangeable technologies (JavaScript vs. CSS) or different technologies within the same stack (Java Grid Controls).

Comment: My gut feeling is that the appropriate way to increase the visibility would be for the user to find an existing Big Query question that this answer fits, or ask a new one and self answer, then comment on the easier to find `tsql` question with something like: "For anyone who lands here when looking for how to do this in Google Big Query, see [this question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) for the proper syntax." But I feel like there's already a Meta question about this with better guidance, I just can't find it.

Comment: @DavyM thanks, good points. I also had the idea to suggest creating a new question (if needed). But I am still wondering.

Comment: @DavyM I think it should be an answer - could you convert your comment into one? Even if someone finds good duplicate later so be it... at least we can vote on proposal in mean time.

Comment: In this specific case can we assume that the right syntax is **not** valid tsql? The person landing on that popular question is presumably looking for a query that will run in ms sql (or possibly sybase) products. If they try the query in the answer, and it does not work then is it truly of high quality?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch exactly, it wont work in that environment as intended.

Comment: Related: [What to do with answers in a different programming language than the one asked for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375424/2675154)

Comment: If it's utterly useless (i.e. can't help at all, even tangentially, as it's not translatable) for the actual question then its clearly not an answer.

Comment: Moreover, it is dubious that attaching the answer to a different-technology question would improve its discoverability.  At least, when *I'm* scanning Google results, I mentally filter based on headline, and if an SO hit passes that then I further filter by the question details before paying attention to any answers.  I suppose anyone who uses search engines effectively does similar, so I don't think intentionally misplacing an answer as described helps much of anyone.

Comment: Lets build some quality. If this need a question under the correct tag so be it. We don't post C# answer on Php tag for more visibility. Either we have a answer that will fit at hand or we create one. If we could create a good one It may ends being a good duplicate target for previously existing question Under this tag tha escape our research

Comment: I generally downvote these and vote to delete where possible. It may increase visibility for one constituency but it has an adverse effect on the signal to noise ratio for others who then have to plough through answers not remotely relevant to their platform

Comment: Related: [Technically off-topic answer, but seems to be helpful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361666/technically-off-topic-answer-but-seems-to-be-helpful)?

Comment: [About 'off topic' answer flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377539/can-we-add-off-topic-to-the-list-of-answer-flags/377551?noredirect=1#comment654272_377551).

Comment: The short answer to that is "no". The long answer is "f**k no". - https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/167274-the-short-answer-to-that-is-no-the-long-answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is this fine - in general or for discoverability's sake?

In cases where there is no interoperability/interchangeable code, this is definitely **not** OK, and such answers should be downvoted and deleted, for the same reason that it's not OK for fifteen answers that all give the same exact solution: **this content is not useful.**

If you are looking for how to Foo a Bar in, say, the Klingon programming language, and someone posts an answer on how to Foo a Bar when using the Esperanto programming language, that's not helpful or useful to you, nor is it likely to be useful to people trying to do it in Esperanto... because they won't be looking for their solution in a question about doing something in the Klingon language.

> The linked answers address a slightly different scenario, i.e. interchangeable technologies (JavaScript vs. CSS)

To speak to your specific example, I even strongly dislike and discourage this with things that are quite interoperable like CSS and JavaScript. While JS can apply CSS styles, my recommendation is always "don't provide a JS answer" unless the OP explicitly mentions they're willing to use non-CSS solutions, or if the thing literally cannot be done at all in CSS (but can in JS), but preferably only after explaining that/why it can't be done in CSS.

In another scenario, I would feel frustrated if I asked how to do something in ASP.NET with WebForms and someone gave an answer along the lines of - "here's how you do this in MVC".

---

> Or actually not-an-answer?

Do not, however, flag such a thing as "Not An Answer"; it will get declined due to the gymnastic interpretation of that flag by moderators and users. The current consensus (if you can call it that) is that, despite the verbiage of the NAA flag's description, something is only validly NAA if it could not possibly be an answer to *any* question on the site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially the part on NNA flag interpretations. I already got a few of those declined - this is also why I hesitated and asked instead here.

Comment: I've been declined a NAA flag even to an answer that couldn't have been an answer to *any* question to the site... It was a *poem* that made zero sense in the context of *any* question. The current interpretation of NAA is that the NAA *matches* one of the alternatives: link only, asks a question, "I have the same problem", "thanks", "edit to post" - if it does not look like any of these in the first 2 seconds of viewing, it is a non-NAA.

Comment: @Antti Now I really want to read that poem.

Comment: "it will get declined due to the gymnastic interpretation of that flag by moderators and *some* users" if I came along such review, I would vote for recommend deletion. If I found it while having delete votes on answers, I would also vote to delete.

Comment: For example, the following kinds of "answers" are not NAA: "I am not going to show you because it is too long, but here are links to some random tutorials" - the other answers do answer in post in a text of half-screen length.

Comment: I usually follow [Shog's guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) (the image with the apples) when flagging answers and it works wonders. Of course sometimes the moderator disagrees with me but it's normal, and it's marginal in the long run. Most of the times they will also follow this guide, which removes most of the ambiguities, and validate the flag. In this specific case, I usually flag Very Low Quality if the answer uses language/technology different from the question (and leave a comment asking the poster to edit it with the relevant language/technology).

Comment: @Braiam Yes, there are some bastions of sense left on the subject of course...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Actually a link-only answer is one valid example of NAA (see the link in Moritz' comment below yours, specifically the apple diagram).

Comment: @TylerH but it is not a link-only answer. It says that answer would be too long and then the link.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That still qualifies as link-only according to everyone I think you'll find approving or rejecting NAA flags.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that's the equivalent of putting a sign to where to buy apples.

Comment: s/gymnastic/inane

Comment: For older answers which collected lots of upvotes, "downvote and then delete" is not really practical. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073833 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/7150998

Comment: @user202729 It's implied that you should do each of those things only when possible. E.g. advice to downvote is likewise not useful for people with less than 250 rep.

Comment: @Moritz I also think that Shog's apples diagram makes a good argument. However I know I've seen Shog *himself* say that it wasn't accurate *even at the time he posted it.* So, YMMV.