# where does SO stand on answers versus alternatives?

Tags: discussion, answers, xy-problem

When using the site, the greatest difficulty I have is running into multitudes of responses that try and offer an *alternative* when what I’m looking for is an *answer*.

I realize that alternatives can be very valuable, especially to beginners and and in response to questions that are not well formulated, but alternatives seem somewhat distinct from answers to me.

I feel like I would find it useful to be able to filter alternative and answer responses and prohibit alternative responses on some questions I ask (I’ve tried stating that I’m not interested in alternatives in the question body, but it seems many people that provide alternatives don't read much past the subject).

Especially with difficult and detailed questions, alternative answers seem to appear rapidly and easily draw support: it's much easier to understand "why don't you just do something somewhat-similar that I’m familiar with".

I want to understand if SO draws a distinction between alternatives and answers, and how it feels about both of their roles in the sites?

Comment: Related: http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925

Comment: Are you sure you've clearly and adequately described your constraints?

Comment: You'll have to put up with it.  SO is not a personal helpdesk, the Q+A needs to be useful to more than one programmer and that includes the consideration for alternatives.

Comment: Consider my answer here: [What can I do about posters that derail the question with a discussion about best practices?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267153) Did you show you are aware of those alternatives? And have you carefully explained why those alternative solutions are inappropriate?

Comment: well-formulating the question is usually an iterative approach as you see how people respond, same as with proofs and papers and the like :) one of the issues with alternatives by nature is that i don't think it's often possible to exhaustively cover them.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179567/217863

Comment: after reading this and the answer below, basically, i think i'm taking it to seriously... i don't need to accept answers that don't solve my problem and responses that don't apply to it might be useful for others. the site has a lot of great information on it and i can take sifting through alternative suggestions as part of it. thanks guys.

Comment: You're welcome! I've always thought the fact that there's people showing you alternatives is one of the most instructive aspects of SO long term. I myself have been put back on the right path that way.

Comment: Quite often, the way the OP's trying to do something is the very reason it doesn't work. Alternatives can in those cases provide a working solution, _and_ show the OP how something could be done better.

Comment: Think of it this way--"I'm hitting myself in the head with a hammer. It hurts. What kind of helmet should I buy?" "Uh, stop hitting yourself in the head with a hammer." "OMG Y U NO ANSWER MY Q?"  Foolish attitude, is it not?

Comment: @Will: the usual context of such questions is that it is meant as A Learning Experience. Some lessons hurt more than others, probably to make sure [you remember it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zF6xmsrAVk).

Answer (score 12):

You are free to accept any answer you consider "most helpful", whether it is an exact answer to the specific question, an even better alternative (why not?), or even a textual description of the steps to take to answer your own question.

In addition, you are free to *ignore* any answers of which you feel do *not* help you. They still may help others with the exact same question but with other levels of expertise, or - if your question is of the kind "I have to do X but cannot use Y" - do not have such a constraint.

Comment: ok, you're right - even saying that alternatives are no use to me is discouraging knowledge dissemination that could help people with different constraints. people get pretty worked up here about stuff and i think i'm just buying into that too much, which is not good. thanks, this helps.